# Writing to a text file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, text, file-io

I've come across numerous ways to write matlab data to a .txt file but I am unsure which way would be best suited for my needs - I have two sets of data labelled 'x' and 'y' within which data simply runs down 1 column (A1....An) and I need a tab delimited .txt file made with the format:

```
Name   X    X    Y
Test   2    2    5.5
Test   3    3    6.5
Test   4    4    7.5
```

etc...

Whereby I can have 2 identical columns of the X data, followed by the Y data. I also need to be able to input something for the 'Name' column which will copy itself down until the data in X/Y stops. I don't need any column headers in it i.e. 'X' 'Y' or 'Name' just the data itself.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Don't know how your data looks like, but assuming it's already a cell of cars: `fprintf(fid,'%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n',c{:})`

Comment: Exactly @DanielR, sorry I didn't see your comment before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this code example and you can check that it does what you want:

```
% Example data:
x = [1:5];
y = rand(1,5);

fileID = fopen('yourfile.txt','w');
for i = 1:length(x)
    fprintf(fileID,'%s\t%d\t%d\t%f\n', 'Test', x(i),x(i),y(i));
end
fclose(fileID);
```

Opening the text file you will see something like:

```
Test    1   1   0.655741
Test    2   2   0.035712
Test    3   3   0.849129
Test    4   4   0.933993
Test    5   5   0.678735
```

If you want the value for string 'Test' to change in each row, simply pass in an array with those string values, similar to how the x and y variables are passed to the fprintf() statement.

Comment: Is there a way I can add a header to the data (consisting of solely text) that only appears in the first line?

Comment: Oh yes, just use: fprintf(fileID, '%s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t \n', 'Name', 'X','X','Y')

Answer (score 0):

One way is to first put everything into a single cell:

```
Name = repmat({'Test'}, [1 DataSize]); % A Cell containing n 'Test' string

C = [Name num2cell(X') num2cell(X') num2cell(Y')]; % Concatenating cells
```

Then use `fprintf` to write the cell into a file:

```
fid = fopen('data.txt', 'wt');
fprintf(fid, '%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\n', C{:});
fclose(fid);
```

Hope it helps.